# Show that $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) = \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$ and this implies $A=B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

$\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) = \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B) \implies A = B$

Let $S \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$.

Thus, $S \subseteq A \cap B$.

Thus $S\subseteq A$ and $S \subseteq B$. $\to$ From here I'm not quite sure how to proceed, because I try to show that $\mathcal{P}(A\cap B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)\cup \mathcal{P}(B)$.

Also I don't know how to show that this implies that $A = B$.

Comment: What is $P$ in this context?

Comment: P is considered as partition

Comment: Assuming that "$P$" means "power set", then in general, $P(A \cap B)=P(A) \cap P(B)$ for any two sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question so that it matches the body of the question.

Comment: @C4995658 Please use appropriate tags for your question ! I don't see how any of the tags you used are relevant. Make sure to read a tags description before using one. Maybe you could use the "elementary set theory tag" here ?

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang: the question has a $\cup$ and a $\cap$ not two $\cap$s.

Comment: Your edit to the title is still wrong: it should be a conditional statement not a conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: draw Venn diagrams for a few simple cases, e.g., $A, B \subseteq \{1, 2\}$. That should help you to see that if $\mathcal{P}(A \cap B) = \mathcal{P}(A) \cup \mathcal{P}(B)$, then $A$ can't have any elements that aren't in $B$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can **not** show that $\mathcal P(A\cap B)=\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)$, because it is a contingency (not always true).

You may show that *if* it were so, then $A=B$.  And you have done most of the heavy lifting for that.

---

Suppose $\mathcal P(A\cap B)=\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)$.

Since $A\in\mathcal P(A)$ by definition, therefore $A\in\mathcal P(A)\cup\mathcal P(B)$.   The supposition thereby entails $A\in\mathcal P(A\cap B)$, and as you have argued …

> Let $S \in \mathcal{P}(A \cap B)$.
>
> Thus, $S \subseteq A \cap B$.
>
> Thus $S\subseteq A$ and $S \subseteq B$.

… therefore $A\subseteq B$ is entailed by the supposition.

Likewise since $B\in\mathcal P(B)$, we may derive $B\subseteq A$ from the supposition.

Therefore $A=B$ is entailed by the supposition.